# Index overflow in VHDL std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have a doubt in following VHDL code regarding index overflow of `len`:

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;    
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;  
    package mypack is  
       subtype small_int is integer range 0 to 3;    
    end mypack;

library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;    
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;    
    use work.mypack.all;   
entity top is    
   port(
        CLK        : in std_logic;    
        rst        : in std_logic;
        myPtr      : in small_int; 
        temp       : in unsigned(1 downto 0); 
        myout     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));    
end entity;    

architecture rtl of top is
   signal len : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)  := (others=>'0');         
   constant si : small_int := 1;
begin
    myout    <= len;
    process(clk,rst) begin
       if (RST='1') then
          len <= "0000";
       elsif rising_edge(CLK) then 
          len(myPtr - si) <= temp(0);         
       end if; 
    end process;    
end architecture;
```

What should be correct behaviour when `myPtr = 0`:

1. Would `len(3) <= temp(0);` happen?
2. Or, would there be an index over flow situation? Which means, `len(3)` will always remain at `0`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if myPtr=0 and you have a rising edge event, then len(myPtr-si)<=temp(0) would be len(0-1)<=temp(0) and you'll have a negative index... and i'm pretty sure that's not OK.

Comment: The most obvious potential potential problem  is when MyPtr = 0 minus 1 (si)  gives -1 which is out of out of range of MyPtr (small_int range 0 to 3) and out of bounds of len (3 downto 0).

Comment: Exactly what I wrote!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names para 3 "...For the evaluation of an indexed name, the prefix and the expressions are evaluated. It is an error if an index value does not belong to the range of the corresponding index range of the array."  (I'm more than pretty sure that's not OK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simulation, an out of range index value will generate an error.

In hardware, and out of range index value result in undefined operation, so any or no update may occur.

Comment: NB at least one simulator out there (Xilinx ISIM, many versions) turns range checking OFF by default. Find the switch and turn ON...